# Why am I receiving "INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST" when creating a new apex page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, rest-api, apexpage

I'm currently experimenting with creating a new Apex page from API. I'm using the API Explorer as this is the fastest for me.

```
{
  "Name": "Test Page",
  "Markup": "<apex:page standardController=\"Lead\"><apex:outputPanel layout=\"block\" style=\"font-weight:bold\">Test Page</apex:outputPanel></apex:page>",
  "ApiVersion": 39,
  "Description": "This is a test page",
  "MasterLabel": "Test Page",
  "ControllerKey": "Lead",
  "ControllerType": "Standard"
}
```

I'm trying to `POST` this to the `/services/data/v39.0/sobjects/ApexPage` endpoint, and I'm receiving the following `400` response:

```
[
  {
    "message": "Controller Type: bad value for restricted picklist field: Standard",
    "errorCode": "INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST",
    "fields": [
      "ControllerType"
    ]
  }
]
```

According to the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/api-explorer/sobject/ApexPage/post-apexpage) the ControllerType I'm supplying is right as I'm trying to tie this page to a standard sObject (Lead) but I might get it totally wrong.

Would you please help me out with this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working with following response.

```
{
  "Name": "TestPage1",
  "Markup": "<apex:page standardController=\"Lead\"><apex:outputPanel layout=\"block\" style=\"font-weight:bold\">Test Page</apex:outputPanel></apex:page>",
  "ApiVersion": 41,
  "Description": "This is a test page",
  "MasterLabel": "Test Page",
  "ControllerKey": "Lead"
}
```

Remove the `"ControllerType": "standardController"` and one more thing page name should only contain alpha-numeric characters &/or underscore.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I thought that the ControllerType is a mandatory parameter. Is there a way to figure out (using the API Explorer or documentation) which parameters are required and which are not?

Comment: yes, we need some more information on documentation.I did trial-and-error. I noticed for name it is mentioned as "Required". 

Link: 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_apexpage.htm

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is a typo in their docs there then, have you tried sending

```
"ControllerType": "standard"
```

Or

```
"ControllerType": "standardController"
```

I tried to test this myself but the API explorer won't accept my developer sandbox at all.